# Терминальная утилита, сохранение файлов Obj-c

Tags: objective-c

Создал в Xcode проект Terminal - Fundation, написал простой код сохраняющий данные на диск. Если путь указан к папке документов, то все отлично сохраняется, если я указываю произвольный путь, то файлы не создаются. В чём может быть дело? Chomd 755 делал, запускал как sudo, результат тот же.

Comment: Можете показать код?

Comment: И не только код, но и пример пути, по которому пытаетесь сохранить файлы — мало ли.

Comment: Код записи данных в файл: [[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:testData] writeToFile:[currentPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:TEST_FILENAME] atomically:YES];

Путь по которому не сохраняет: "/Users/myname/Projects.localized"

Сохраняет только в папку документов.

Comment: Проблема была в том, что путь передаваемый консольной утилите не преобразовывался из UTF8, а использовался как есть. В результате сохранение происходило только в папки с англоязычными названиями, рускоязычные папки выглядели в виде двухбайтовых обозначений. Всем спасибо.

// Get current path
        NSString *currentPath;
        if (argc)
        {
            currentPath = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:argv[argc - 1]];
        }